# Merging my dataframes creates a very large product

Tags: pandas, merge

I have a dataframe with lots of schools and their postcodes, some of the postcodes are blank. In another dataframe I have compiled all of the rows with blank postcodes from the first dataframe, and added their postcode. I'd like to combine my two dataframes back together so that I have a complete set - but when I merge my dataframe, I seem to get a many to many relationship with an exponentially larger product.

The first dataframe is called "full" and the second dataframe is called "all_w_postcodes"

[Original Dataframe with blank postcodes included](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PedkC.png)

[Dataframe containing rows from original dataframe with blank postcodes, now with postcodes added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U3fBy.png)

I had tried to do a join using this code: full_all_w_postcodes = full.merge(all_w_postcodes, how='right', on='School Name')

When I changed the parameter for the type of merge to "right", "inner", or "left", I get the same amount of rows each time.

My original dataframe has 91359 rows; my merged dataframe contains 43,672,301 rows.

Any ideas how I could go about this in a better way / what I'm doing wrong?

Cheers!

Comment: You're getting so many rows in the result because you're joining on a merge key with what looks like many, many duplicate values in it. So any and every row from one DataFrame with a particular key value is merged onto any and every row on the other DataFrame. Could you post some self-contained example data and code as text, not images?

Comment: Ah, thank you - I see what I've done here. I solved the problem by using the drop_duplicates function on a column that contained unique ID's which returned the exact number of rows as my original dataset. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having the same issue, the problem here was that I was creating a many to many relationship. I solved the problem by using the drop_duplicates function on a column that contained unique ID's which returned the exact number of rows as my original dataset.